# Activate checkbox value sent from Excel sheet in userform

Tags: excel, vba

Since a while I have been trying to make this work but in spite of my thorough Internet searches the answer keeps eluding me.
I made a userForm in VBA Excel with some textboxes en checkboxes. These values are sent to a sheet in the excel file. The checkboxes represent categories so multiple choices can be selected. The value is translated to true = "x" and false = "" before it is send to the sheet.

```
If userForm.checkbox1.Value = True Then
    ws.Rows.Cells(row, 9).Value = "X"
Else
    ws.Rows.Cells(row, 9).Value = ""
End If
```

The information put in the sheet can be retrieved and edited by using almost the same userForm.
This form has a row selection box with which the desired row can be summoned and the corresponding data populates the userform. The "x" is translated back like this:

```
If ws1.Rows.Cells(row, 9).Value = "X" Then
    userFormedit.checkbox1.Value = True
Else
    userFormedit.checkbox1.Value = False
End If
```

The problem is that the selected checkboxes show the desired value but in grey.
When sending the information back to the sheet, these values are not "seen".
So on the sheet these values disappear. One option is to re-check all the boxes again.
This is not what I desire since a lot of people are going to use this form and that would be time consuming and impractical.
Is there a way to activate/enable the checkboxes?

Comment: Can you post the all the relevant checkbox event codes as well. Your checkboxes will not get disabled if you are not disabling it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider sending from User form to sheet in a `_Click()` and loading sheet values to Form in an `_Activate` sub, e.g.

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
    If CheckBox1.Value Then
        [A1] = "X"
    Else
        [A1] = ""
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    If [A1] = "X" Then
        Me.CheckBox1 = True
    Else
        Me.CheckBox1 = False
    End If
End Sub
```

If a checkbox is shown in grey, the reason could be that it was disabled by the same or another piece of code or from the element's property window (`CheckBox1.Enabled = False`).

Also mind that Excel is not really multi-user friendly. Once multiple users have opened the same Excel, it resides in their PC's memory and other peoples' changes are not visible unless they are closing & reopening the file.

Comment: Thank you, it was indeed in the code where is was deactivated again. It now works beautifully. On the subject of the multi-user issue, I use a filesharing system where you "check-out" a file when using it and it becomes unaccesible to others. When saving the changed file and closing the program it becomes available again. Thank you again for youre answer.

Comment: welcome ... if the question is answered please consider accepting it so its status gets changed ... thanks